# Similar WHERE clause in a long UNION statement in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In a stored procedure, I need to `INSERT` the result of a long `UNION` into a temp table.
The `WHERE` clause is the same for all tables, which is being in a `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Simplified for readability, it goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO #MyTemp
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 in (SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds) UNION
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab2 WHERE col1 in (SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds) UNION
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab3 WHERE col1 in (SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds) UNION
  .
  .
  .
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab20 WHERE col1 in (SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds)
```

Although `TabIds` is a small temp table, typically 3-6 records long, this seems to be pretty inneficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

***Summarizing my question:***

Is there a way I can do `SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds` just once and assign it to a kind of array/list/set (not to another temp table) and just use that in the `WHERE` clauses, and if there is a way, does it really matter for such a small (3-6 recs) temp table?

Comment: Sounds like you should consider normalizing instead of saving typing...

Comment: Background: these tables (tab1...tab20) are part of an existing system that I can't change. What I'm doing is adding reporting using SSRS. That's why I want to do everything in one stored proc, to avoid too much repeating of queries. That said, how would I normalize this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you create, say, a view?

Comment: My problems with view, generally speaking is that I believe (I could be wrong) that they are slower than stored procs. And in this case in particular, these tab1...tabn can be pretty big, in the 100s of 1000s and I just need a few that match a criteria that is passed as a param.

Comment: Views are not "slower than stored procedures" - they are completely different modules used for completely different purposes. Underlying structure and indexes have much more impact on speed of a query than whether you go through a view or not. I'm not sure where you learned that, but if you see some official source that says views are slower than stored procedures, could you tell us where it is so we can correct it?

Comment: @Amarundo 100k rows is pretty small for most shops.  If you have proper design and indexing it shouldn't be an issue.  I have views with close to 1B rows that run just fine.

Comment: What part is inefficient?  Have you done analysis of the individual selects?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - regarding performance the second paragraph after the first bullet list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28SQL.80%29.aspx) seems to say there's a slight performance advantage. But in my case, I also need parameters.

Comment: @Amarundo a SQL Server 2000 document that states "stored procedures ***can*** also improve performance" does not translate to a blanket statement like "views are slower than stored procedures." There is a ***lot*** of ***it depends*** in that statement. And again, a stored procedure is not a view replacement. If a view sucks performance-wise, calling it from a stored procedure does not magically fix it. And if a view has a query that sucks performance-wise, running the same sucky query from a stored procedure does not magically fix it either.

Comment: Why is your criteria `not to another temp table`? What if, like your assertion that views are slower than stored procedures, this is a case where using another #temp table is actually the most efficient way to do this, you just don't think it is?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - because since both are in disk I thought the performance advantage from an already `DISTINCT`ed table to the original one would be negligible.

Comment: @Amarundo please stop discounting solutions (like views or #temp tables) because of your pre-conceived notions about these things. They exist for a reason. If someone offers you a solution with one or the other or both, be open-minded about it. TEST IT. If it proves to perform worse, then okay, at least you gave it a chance. Right now I have no interest in helping you solve the problem because you're eliminating multiple potential solutions because of what you think rather than what you know. This is quite stifling to the conversation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I really appreciate your help and can't understand your strong reaction to all this. If you read my posts you see that I'm not discounting anything, but at the moment of writing it I chose one way over another. Read again and you'll see I say thing like "I could be wrong", or "I thought". Not at all what you say. And in any case I still have a parameter to pass so (I could be wrong) views are out. Again, I appreciate your help and the time you  put in this for a total unknown person. Thanks.

Comment: You said "(not to another temp table)" - why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Because as it is, there may be 3-6 rows in the temp table. If I do another temp table with `DISTINCT` values I may go down to 2-4 rows. I thought that the improved performance, if any, would be negligible, and the added complexity (small, granted, but it all adds up) would not make it worthwhile.

Comment: Right now you repeat `SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds` 20 times. How many total rows in `TabIds`? How many distinct values of `myId`? How much work does SQL Server do *each time* to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: @AaronBertrand `TabId`s range from 5k to 100k records each.

Comment: And you don't think dumping those IDs only, to a #temp table clustered on ID, performing a scan and a distinct *once*, might be more efficient than doing that 20 times?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, it has to be more efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm ignoring your requirement ("not to another temp table") because I don't believe it is well-founded. Try and see if this solution gives you better performance:

```
SELECT i = myId
  INTO #x 
  FROM dbo.TabIds -- please always use schema prefix
  GROUP BY myId;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON #x(i);

INSERT INTO #MyTemp(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.tab1 WHERE EXISTS -- likely better than IN
    (SELECT 1 FROM #x WHERE i = tab1.col1)
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.tab2 WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM #x WHERE i = tab2.col1)
  UNION ALL

  ...

  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.tab20 WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM #x WHERE i = tab20.col1)
) AS x
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3; -- likely more efficient than `UNION` to remove dupes
```

Of course this will work best if `col1` is indexed in all 20 tables, and if that index includes `col2` and `col3`.

The reason I suggested a view is not because I thought it would make this code run faster. Just that you could create a view that generates this `UNION` for you, making *this* code simpler (and any other code that repeats this monotonous `UNION`). It was a suggestion for convenience, not for performance - though I need to make it clear that using a view does not magically make things slower. Sometimes I can, but that's a dangerous and illogical reason to avoid views.

Finally, I'd strongly consider normalization. Why are these 20 different tables in the first place, when they could all be in one single table?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Normal
(
  SourceTableID INT,
  col1 <data type>,
  col2 <data type>,
  col3 <data type>
);

-- indexes / constraints

INSERT dbo.Normal
SELECT 1, col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.tab2
UNION ALL

...

UNION ALL
SELECT 20, col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.tab20;
```

Now all your queries can simply reference this new table. If you will commonly look for only one of the sources (e.g. `tab5`), then indexing or partitioning on `SourceTableID` would be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't normalize and create one big table. The tables are created by a product that creates a new set of tables (the one I'm referring to here is just one of those) for every, let's call it "new project" that is made in the system. I can't modify that. Your code teaches me a lot of things. I'll study it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing, conceptually, is fine for one-offs and data loads.  I hope this isn't part of a bigger pattern in production code, though.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` goes on the first `SELECT`, not on the one in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

[What you're looking for is a Common Table Expression.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

My T-SQL is a bit rusty, but with a CTE, your query would go something like:

```
WITH TabIds_CTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds)
INSERT INTO #MyTemp
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab1 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT * FROM TabIds_CTE)
UNION ALL ...
```

Comment: It does save you a bit of typing. The optimizer should bring both this query and the original one to the same form.

Comment: Not really, your `IN` isn't correct, still needs to be `IN (SELECT myId FROM TabIds_CTE)`...

Comment: I'll take a look at that link

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might be better for small tables, but still - it's horrible idea to leave it like this in some production process :)

```
INSERT INTO #MyTemp (col1,col2,col3)
select distinct
    x.col1,x.col2,x.col3 
from (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab1 union all
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab2 union all 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab3 union all 
  -- ...
  SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab20
) x
join (
    SELECT DISTINCT myId FROM TabIds
) y
on x.col1=y.myid
```